# Qt Debugging: I am implementing a Qt thread class that is not being recognized when used, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qthread

So I have implemented a thread class in my program that I'm trying to run from my mainwindow, but it is not being recognized. I will post below the thread header and file, as well as the main window header and file.

CONTEXT: The thread contains a loop that goes through the files in a directory and sends a signal to print the title to the mainwindow.

directoryprinter.h (Thread header)

```
#ifndef DIRECTORYPRINTER_H
#define DIRECTORYPRINTER_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QtCore/QDir>
#include <QtCore/QDirIterator>

class DirectoryPrinter : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DirectoryPrinter(QObject *parent = 0);
    void DirectoryParser();
    void run();

signals:
    void SendSignal(QString);

private:
    QDirIterator * it;    
};

#endif // DIRECTORYPRINTER_H
```

Thread class definitions

```
#include "directoryprinter.h"

DirectoryPrinter::DirectoryPrinter(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    it = new QDirIterator ("C:Users/Andrew/",QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
}

void DirectoryPrinter::DirectoryParser()
{
    while (it->hasNext())
    {
        QString String = it->next();
        SendSignal(String);
    }
}

void DirectoryPrinter::run()
{
    this->DirectoryParser();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include "directoryprinter.h"

//UNINITIALIZED POINTERS??

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void Print(QString String);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_released();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    DirectoryPrinter *Name; //THIS LINE IS NOT RECOGNIZED
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(Name,SIGNAL(SendSignal(QString)),this,SLOT(Print(QString)));
    }

void MainWindow::Print(QString String)
{
    ui->textBrowser->setText(String);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_released()
{
    Name = new DirectoryPrinter();
    Name->start();
}
```

The program exits with: exited with code -1073741819

However, I believe the issue is with the line I commented above. I am unsure where to begin debugging this, I have a few ideas, but they'd mostly be guesses, and I do not have much experience using threads.

Thanks in advance. et me know if there is any further information required.

Comment: What do you mean by "not being recognized"?

Comment: Sorry about not going into more detail about that. As in, I would sometimes be drawing up an error where it would say in `DirectoryPrinter *Name;` there was an expected semi colon before the * or something of the sort. I couldn't reproduce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(Name,SIGNAL(SendSignal(QString)),this,SLOT(Print(QString)));
}
```

In `MainWindow`'s constructor, you're connecting a signal from an object that hasn't been initialized (you don't initialize `Name` until `on_pushButton_released()` is called).  To fix this, create `Name` in the constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Name = new DirectoryPrinter(this);//this is the parent; takes care of cleanup
    connect(Name,SIGNAL(SendSignal(QString)),this,SLOT(Print(QString)));
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_released()
{
    //Name = new DirectoryPrinter(); not needed here anymore
    Name->start();
}
```

From the comment below, there is another problem here - namely, `MainWindow::Print` is not defined as a `slot` (using the `slots:` macro).  It should be:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    //void Print(QString String); // <-- not here...
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void Print(QString String); // <-- here instead

// ...other class-definition stuff
};
```

Comment: Hi there! That seems to have gotten rid fo that issue. However, is the signal/slot connection implemented properly? I seem to be getting this now: Object::connect: No such slot MainWindow::Print(QString)
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')

Comment: Edited.  You should also consider taking the string by reference (`QString&`) or constant reference (`const QString&`) in that slot, rather than by copy.

Comment: There are a few reasons to prefer not using a `const` reference for the `QString` parameter. Qt uses implicit sharing for `QString`s so there would be little efficiency to gain. Slot signatures are normalized so `const` references will be replaced with values. Finally, if you normalize your signature ahead of time, the lookup will be slightly faster.

Comment: I would argue that `const QString&` is always preferable. There are many non-intuitive ways for you to accidentally cause your implicitly shared data to get `detach`ed. Also note how every function in the Qt API that takes in a QString does so with a const reference, without exception.

Comment: I would have to agree that at the very least, `const` references communicate the intent unambiguously. Slots and signals would be an exception to that general rule.

Comment: Arnold/Chris: There are two completely orthogonal issues here. In function *declarations*, you should always use const references for "in" parameters. In `QObject::connect()` calls, always use normalized signatures with outer `const` and `&` removed. So, connecting to `slot(const QString & foo, int a, int b)`, you'd connect to `SLOT(slot(QString,int,int)))`. Note the absence of unnecessary spaces, too.